# How To Return Multiple Match Values from A Cell That Contains A Word/Text in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a bunch of data that consist of Id Number and Names.

*Image 1*

[image]

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$12;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$16=$E$1;ROW($A$1:$A$12));ROW(1:1));2));"";INDEX($A$1:$B$12;SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$16=$E$1;ROW($A$1:$A$12));ROW(1:1));2))}
```

Previously (Image 1) I successfully able to return multiple value with A Name value from column Names that consist of only one name. I am using Index function Array formula to solve this problem.

But,I got stuck when I have multiple names in that Names column. What I want to do is to return multiple value of Id Number that consist of a multiple names separated by 'comma' inside Names column without modifying that column. Expected result is shown in Image 2.

Image 2

[image]

The problems are :

1. I want to get the value from the ID Number column based on Names
   column that contain a name inside
2. I want to automatically get multiple values just like displayed in
   Image 1
3. If there're two ID Number value that is the same, it will be deleted or not be shown in the result.

I don't mind any kind of method you guys will purposed to me. I will appreciate any solutions you offered. Thank you very much.

Comment: Instead of using `Index()` to find your matches, you will need to use the `Find()` formula to find matches within cells, rather then matching complete cells. To check if a match is present you can see if `Find()` produces a result larger then 0.

Comment: Why does `John` only match with `1a232` when it also appears in other rows?

Comment: And Marrie's ID should only appear once because she is repeated with the same number?

Comment: I edited the image 2. thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(E$1,$B$2:$B$11))*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11)=0),ROW($B$2:$B$11)),1)),"")
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$11)/(ISNUMBER(FIND(E$1,$B$2:$B$11))*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11)=0)),1)),"")
```

entered normally.

[image]

**EDIT**

@Ron Rosenfeld is absolutely correct that the formulas as they stand would match (for example) Jo as well as John, although the effect is mitigated somewhat by the fact that they are using case-sensitive find with a capital letter at the beginning of each name (so Ange wouldn't match Hanger).

The modified formulas would be

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&E$1&",",","&$B$2:$B$11&","))*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11)=0),ROW($B$2:$B$11)),1)),"")
```

and

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$11)/(ISNUMBER(FIND(","&E$1&",",","&$B$2:$B$11&","))*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$11)=0)),1)),"")
```

Comment: I would suggest adding a comma to both  `find_text` and `within_text` so as to avoid the issue of *names within names*.  eg `find(e1&",", b2:b11 & ",")`

Comment: Thank you so much mr @Tom Sharpe It works really well. I should have learn a lot more about excel. :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Ron Rosenfeld - plz see edit.